# WatchOS app launched by tapping an associated file

Tags: swiftui, apple-watch, watchos

In iPhone, if you open Files app and tap on an associated file type, its corresponding app is launched. I have implemented this functionality in my iOS SwiftUI app - associated a file type .csk with my iOS app and handled its launch using the [onOpenURL(perform:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/onopenurl(perform:)) modifier.

```
WindowGroup {
    FileContentView()
        .onOpenURL(perform: { (fileUrl: URL) in

            Log(String(format: "File Url = %@", fileUrl.absoluteString))
      
            // Update UI with the content of the file
        })
}
```

I want to achieve the same for my watchOS app. I noticed that the [UTExportedTypesDeclaration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/utexportedtypedeclarations) key, which is used to declare the file types created and owned by the app, is not available for watchOS. But the [CFBundleDocumentTypes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cfbundledocumenttypes) key, which is used to associate a file type with the app is available. So, I expect my app to respond to taps on those associated file types, but I've run into a snag. There is no Files app in AppleWatch nor is there a way to view my iCloud storage. I have my .csk file (which is associated with the watchOS app) in iCloud.

So, how can I test this launch? How can a AppleWatch user tap a file and view it in his app? It should be possible to handle file launches since CFBundleDocumentTypes is available for watchOS.